# Javadoc text for variables within main method

Tags: java, javadoc

I was wondering if it is possible to generate Javadoc text for important variables within the main method of a class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /**
     * Writes statistical information to results file
     */
    BufferedWriter report_stream = null; 
    ....
```

This is an example of a variable whose description I would like displayed in Javadoc. 
Thanks.

Comment: Nope. That said, the necessity of doing that is somewhat suspect; if a method is big enough that its variables need external documentation something may be wrong.

Comment: (You might be after something in the "literate programming" vein if you're looking to *explain* code, as opposed to documenting it.)

Answer (score 2):

No. Javadoc is for generating documentation of the API, not the implementation.

However you could wrap the buffered writer in another class and document that, if required.